# Find Real Fine-grained Parallel Scientific Applications that use MPI + OpenMP Task

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmp, scientific-computing

I am currently working on a project that we slightly modified the OpenMP code. We have googled and looked into the OpenMP forum but could not find real fine-grained parallel scientific applications that are based on MPI+OpenMP tasking.

We want to evaluate our changes with some real scientific applications using MPI+OpenMP tasking and understand how it performs.
It would be greatly appreciated if someone could point us to some open-source sites where we could just download and see the numbers. If it is not open-source, we can also try to contact them.

Comment: The use of OpenMP tasks with dependency is relatively new compared to the average age of HPC applications. My understanding is that their adoption is slow, mainly because people want other to do the first step to be convinced and also because it can require a pretty deep rewrite of some computing kernels if not even the whole application. There are many *research papers* taking about this topic though it is quite recent. Some conference have tracks for that. I advise you to check for example Supercomputing, IWOMP, Europar, etc.

Comment: It is hard to come up with simple cases where MPI+OMP is better than pure MPI. There are probably large research codes that use it, but I doubt that you could "just download" them.

Comment: I would doubt the utility, for your purposes, of downloading a 'real' scientific code using MPI and OpenMP tasks.  Many such codes are so complex that it will be very difficult to make small, incremental changes, and to clearly observe their impacts in isolation from confounding factors.